# Is having different iOS bundle ID from android package name bad?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

What are the downsides of different android package name and iOS bundle ID in React Native?

Answer (score 4):

See at the end package name is what uniquely identifies your app in the respective `app store` and `playstore`.

There maybe a case where you have the desired bundleId taken by some other app etc, in that case you have to use a differnt bundle/app id.

There are no down side of different package name and bundle id . Just make sure you have a proper bundleId / package name which suits your app well. I mean thats one of the criteria what depends on which app it shows first when user searches suppose programming, then a programming related app shows which has suppose `app.programming.learn` in its package name. So just be wise. You can have different names.

Hope its clear. Feel free for doubts